# Is it possible to use a SHA512 digest in MS Access 2007

Tags: mysql, database, ms-access, passwords, sha512

We have a MS Access app that uses a mysql database via odbc, which contains a table for user credentials.  The table consists of a username and a crypted password digested with SHA512.  What we are hoping to do is compare the input password to the database crypted password, but cannot find any kind of sha512 digest function for vba that can be readily used in MS Access.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Is a [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) added to these passwords prior to hashing? It should be.

Comment: @Asaph yes there is a salt.  I didn't mention that as to not over complicate my explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not much you can use directly, but if you don't mind installing visual studio, it's quite easy.

You need to create a simple class library in Visual Studio and make it visible as a COM library, here are some good instructions for [Calling a .Net library from Access.](http://richnewman.wordpress.com/2007/08/25/a-beginner%E2%80%99s-guide-to-calling-a-net-library-from-access/)

In the VS class library you just create an instance of the [SHA512 Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxzzak1k.aspx) and call the compute hash method. In VBA you add a reference to the COM library then use it like a local class.